# Why do Webdriver browser windows not close when running more than one suiteXmlFile using TestNG from the Maven command line?

Tags: java, maven, selenium, jenkins, testng

I have 40 Webdriver tests separated into two groups -- one that has to be run serially (where each has the metadata group tag "crm_import") and one that can be run in parallel.  Those two groups are referenced by the following XML files:

```
TestNG.xml

<suite name = "Suite" thread-count="2" parallel="methods">
<test name = "TestSet">
    <groups>
        <run>
            <exclude name = "crm_import"/>
        </run>
    </groups>
    <classes>
        <class name = "com.dcp.test.suite.TestSuite"/>
    </classes>
</test>
</suite>


TestNG_includeOnly.xml

<suite name = "Suite2" verbose="1" >
<test name = "TestSet">
    <groups>
        <run>
            <include name = "crm_import"/>
        </run>
    </groups>
    <classes>
        <class name = "com.dcp.test.suite.TestSuite"/>
    </classes>
</test>
</suite>
```

Those two are referenced within the POM file as follows:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.8</version>
<configuration>
    <suiteXmlFiles>
        <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
        <suiteXmlFile>testng-includeOnly.xml</suiteXmlFile>
    </suiteXmlFiles>
    ...
</configuration>
```

Because I need to run them from within Jenkins when I get the scheme working, I'm using the command line version to run them, using the following to try just running the parallel set:

```
mvn clean test -DsuiteXmlFile=testng.xml site
```

Two problems occur...

1. It runs both sets
2. When the 40 tests run, 38 windows are left open

If I go to the POM file and comment out one suite or the other and just run...

```
mvn clean test site
```

...then everything's fine -- no windows left open, and the parallel tests run in parallel.

If you're wondering how I open and close the browser, here's the skeleton of the base class that the TestSuite.java file extends...

```
public class TestSuiteBase implements IInvokedMethodListener {
...
@Override
public void beforeInvocation(IInvokedMethod method, ITestResult testResult) {
    if (method.isTestMethod()) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette", "/opt/geckodriver"); 
        ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
        String ffProfileName = properties.getProperty("ffProfileName");
        FirefoxProfile myprofile = profile.getProfile(ffProfileName);
        System.out.println("--> creating WebDriver instance..." + "Thread id = " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(myprofile);
        LocalDriverManager.setWebDriver(driver);
    }
}

@Override
public void afterInvocation(IInvokedMethod method, ITestResult testResult) {
    if (method.isTestMethod()) {
        WebDriver driver = LocalDriverManager.getDriver();
        if (driver != null) {
            System.out.println("After Test breakdown, quitting driver..." + "Thread id = " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
            driver.quit();
        }
    }
}
```

In case you're curious as to where I got some of that architecture, I borrowed it from here... https://rationaleemotions.wordpress.com/2013/07/31/parallel-webdriver-executions-using-testng/

Comment: What about using things like `@AfterGroup`, `@AfterTest`etc. ? instead of a listener ?

Comment: I was previously using such constructs, but switched to the listener scheme in order to implement the parallel processing of the one suite.

Comment: When I run the tests, I see the debug statement in the afterInvocation() method, so it's not like it's not being called, so I don't know what advantage changing would bring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The blog that you shared is my blog :)

If you were to be looking at passing in multiple TestNG suites, then you should perhaps take a look at [this](https://rationaleemotions.wordpress.com/2016/03/29/parallel-execution-of-multiple-testng-suites/) blog post of mine. That should basically take care of your issue #1.

For your issue #2 i.e., you having multiple browser windows open, you could perhaps do the following in your `afterInvocation` method :

```
@Override
public void afterInvocation(IInvokedMethod method, ITestResult testResult) {
    if (method.isTestMethod()) {
        WebDriver driver = LocalDriverManager.getDriver();
        if (driver != null) {
            System.out.println("After Test breakdown, quitting driver..." + "Thread id = " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
            driver.quit();
        }
        LocalDriverManager.setWebDriver(null);
    }
}
```

Here we are explicitly nullifying the current thread's webdriver context.

I am not quite sure if its really going to fix the problem, but you could try this and see if that helps.

Comment: Krishnan -- thank you so much for the link to the additional blog post!  It was exactly what I needed to modify my POM file so as to accept an optional XML file on the command line to specify the xml file to use.  That basically solved both issues, but I added the LocalDriverManager nullification as well.

Comment: Actually, what I am now able to do is to specify on the command line `mvn clean test -Dfile={one XML file or the other} site`.  This is great, because I could put the 2 versions of that line in separate Jenkins jobs.  However, when I list both XML files (comma separated of course), they do both run, but that's when I end up with the leftover browser sessions.  What's also odd is that I'm only running a total of 3 tests (2 in parallel and 1 from the normal/serial set) but 4 browsers are opened.  One of them does close successfully.

Comment: @JoeHennessey - Its going to be difficult to pin point on what the problem is without actually seeing code. So how about you create a small reproducible project which an be executed to reproduce the issue and post it on github and share the link with us.